# I'm looking for a way to create a GUI with Python where a user can add nodes and connect them? Also showing some info about the nodes

Tags: python, user-interface, networking, nodes, visualization

I want the network to be interactive (ie. showing info on a node when hovered on). I tried networkx,pyvis, and graphviz but I'm not sure how they can work on a gui as they just output a graph depending on the inputs. I also know about Tkinter for the gui but it's not enough to create interactive network.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use PyQt5.

PyQt5 is a Python binding for the Qt cross-platform application and UI framework. It's a complete binding, offering access to all classes, functions and signals of the Qt library.

Comment: But is it possible to add nodes in a graph ? Like is there something predefined in it that I can use? Cause if not I will have to draw myself